# Display certain variables from inside an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a product array that is coming from a database.

I just want to print all the variables that are called [sku] inside that said array.

If I print it out like this

```
<?php echo $products[0]['sku']; ?>
```

I get only the 1-st value of SKU

how can i display all of the SKU variables without going [0] , [1] , [2] and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will do what you want

```
<?php

foreach ($products as $key => $row) {
    var_export($row['sku']);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1):

You can try print_r, but that will give you all the array values. A simple foreach will do the job and only print the SKU for every product.

```
foreach($products as $value) {
    echo $value['sku'] . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `print_r()` instead of `echo`.

Comment: I don't want to see them only,i want to display the value of SKU as text

Comment: so u want to like display all the values as a sentence right? if that's what you want you can try implode() function.